# This.state undefine after fetch()

Tags: react-native, fetch, state

I have a problem, after I using fetch my this.state is undefine and I don't understand why ....

```
googlePOI(center) {
        this.setState({markerPOI: []});
        var i = 0;
        let call = '';
        call = call.concat(URL_POI, center.lat.toString(), ',', center.lng.toString(), ARG_POI, this.state.filters[i], KEY);
        console.log(this.state) // DEFINE !
        fetch(call)
            .then((answer) => answer.json())
            .then(function(answer) {
                console.log(this.state) // UNDEFINE !
                answer.results.map((item, index) => {
                    let geo = item.geometry.location;
                    let marker = <MapView.Marker title={item.name} coordinate={{latitude: geo.lat, longitude: geo.lng}} />
                })
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log("ERROR: fetch googlePOI -> "+error);
            })

    }
```

Comment: For one, you're never updating your state from the fetch using `this.setState({ someState: someValue })`. Second, if `this.state` is completely undefined, you should provide the code for the rest of your component, certainly your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when the callback of the promise is called, the internal context of the function is changed. In other words `this` is no longer what it used to be! You can do a `console.log(this)` and you will find out for yourself.

The most simple solution would be to keep a reference of `this` on the top:

```
var me = this;

fetch(url).then(function() {
  console.log(me.state)
});
```

Also you can bind this with the callback function:

```
fetch(url).then(function() {
  console.log(this.state)
}.bind(this));
```

Or the most suggested way to use ES2015 Arrows:

```
fetch(url).then(() => {
  console.log(this.state)
});
```

For educational purposes i would suggest an article like [what is this](https://www.sitepoint.com/what-is-this-in-javascript/)

Comment: In react native, this doesn't work for me :(. Inside my fetch response, my 'const t = this' is undefined within the then() statement of my fetch. What am I doing wrong?